# Controller not invoking then with mock service's deferred

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I am trying to mock a method in a service that returns a promise. The controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, foo) {
var self = this;
this.bar = "";

this.foobar = function() {
  console.log('Calling the service.');
  foo.fn().then(function(data) {
    console.log('Received data.');
    self.bar = data;
  });
}

this.foobar();
});
```

The spec file:

```
angular.module('mock.foo', []).service('foo', function($q) {
var self = this;

this.fn = function() {
  console.log('Fake service.')
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve('Foo');
    return defer.promise;
};
});

describe('controller: MainCtrl', function() {
var ctrl, foo, $scope;

beforeEach(module('app'));
// inject the mock service
beforeEach(module('mock.foo'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _foo_) {
  foo = _foo_;
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope , foo: foo });
}));

it('Should call foo fn', function() {
expect($scope.bar).toBe('Foo');
});

});
```

When debugging, I can see in the controller the promise object state being 1 (resolved). Yet, the success callback within `then` is never invoked.

The following Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xpiPKPdjhiaI8KEU1T5V reproduces the scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get a reference to $rootScope in your test and call:

```
$rootScope.$digest()
```

Your plunk, revisited:

[$digest called and test passed.](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuqU9bMl61KpotvPmiT4)

Also your mock didn't return anything in the resolve, I added:

defer.resolve('Foo');

HTH